# Eliminar campos vacios auto - rellenados con NULL en el momento de elimiar los datos de la fila (PHP, MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola a todos, miren tengo una consulta que por mas que busco no lo encuentro o no escribo la pregunta con la sintaxis adequada, miren estoy insertando y eliminando datos de unos articulos de una base de datos de aprendizaje, mi problema surge, cuando depues de insertar un registro y eliminarlo, me elimina los datos escritos pero no la fila que los contiene, y se queda todo escrito NULL. Entonces me ayudarian a decirme cual es el comando a ejecutar que supongoquesera similar a DELETE FROM NOMBRETABLA WHERE NOMBRECAMPO;

---

Tal cual, lo que necesitava, la expresion de como borrar dichos campos. Y error mio no haber comentado que CODIGOARTICULO era clave primaria muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que en tu BBDD el campo CODIGOARTICULO es una clave primaria, puedes ejecutar:

```
DELETE FROM productos WHERE CODIGOARTICULO is NULL;
```

Con eso borraras todos aquellos que el codigoArticulo sea null (que es lo que quieres conseguir)

Comment: Tal cual, lo que necesitava, la expresion de como borrar dichos campos. Y error mio no haber comentado que CODIGOARTICULO era clave primaria muchas gracias!!